# How does Matlab's return control behave in a recursive function?

Tags: matlab, recursion, return

Will it return to the recursive function or to the function that invoked the recursive function?

Comment: Did...you try it?

Comment: [`return`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html): *return forces MATLAB to return control to the invoking function before it reaches the end of the function. **The invoking function is the function that calls the script or function** containing the call to return.* In the first call to your function, it returns out. After that, the function calling your recursive function is the recursive function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my viewpoint, it will return to the recursive function first.

A little test:

function `accu.m`:

```
function [AN] = accu(num,an)
  disp(['recursive function with num = ' num2str(num)])
  if (num==0) 
      AN=an;
      return
  end
  AN=accu(num-1,an+num);
  disp(['recursive function with num = ' num2str(num) '.'])
end
```

when we call `accu(5,0)` it will return:

```
recursive function with num = 5
recursive function with num = 4
recursive function with num = 3
recursive function with num = 2
recursive function with num = 1
recursive function with num = 0
recursive function with num = 1.
recursive function with num = 2.
recursive function with num = 3.
recursive function with num = 4.
recursive function with num = 5.

ans =

    15
```